# Setting JAVA_HOME for root on Red Hat

Tags: java, redhat-enterprise-linux

I inserted the following in '/etc/profile'

JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_21
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

But when I 'sudo su' from my regular account, it does not pick up the above java path: any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try doing

```
sudo su -
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do `sudo su` then su is not a login shell, and file /etc/profile is not processed.
In order to make su a login shell you can call it with `--login`, `-l` or `-` option. So, use `sudo su -`.